# Clang++ and `-fuse-ld=gold` results in many unused option warnings

Tags: cmake, compiler-warnings, clang++

I'm trying to use the `gold` linker with `clang++` in a `CMake` project. If I simply do

```
add_definitions(-fuse-ld=gold)
```

I get tons of warnings in the form:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fuse-ld=gold'
```

- Is the option actually working?
- Where should I add it in my `CMake` script to avoid having warnings all over the place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the option is for link stage, add it to the **linker flags**, not to the *compiler* ones. E.g, you may set variable [CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS.html):

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -fuse-ld=gold")
```

---

Note, that CMake separates linker-related variables for different output type. Variable `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` affects only on linking *executables* (`add_executable()`). For libraries use appropriate `CMAKE_*_LINKER_FLAGS` variable:

- CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS - for *STATIC* libraries
- CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS - for *SHARED* libraries
- CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS - for *MODULE*s.

Comment: Isn't the compiler calling the linker though? The option is there to *select* the linker, not to be passed to it. In fact, `clang++ -fuse-ld=gold -Wl, --version` correctly reports `gold` version, while `clang++ -Wl,-fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--version` will report `ld`, meaning that `clang++` did not call `gold`.

Comment: Yes, CMake (by default) calls compiler for **link stage**. But *linker is unrelated at compile stage*. And the warning message you got means exactly that: linker options are ignored when compiling. When you request version  with `-Wl, --version`, you got *version of the linker*; of course, presence/absence of `-fuse-ld=gold` in that case has a sence.

Comment: I found that setting `CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS` will cause problems because the linker isn't actually used for building static libraries.